# Why the all dataframes become nan when I just assign nan to one of them

Tags: python, dataframe

I created two dataframes from one dataframe values. I'm modifying the two dataframes such that they have some nan rows by index. However, I could assign nan to one of the dataframe. When I do the same thing to another one, all three dataframes become nan.

I tried to use dataframe.values instead of the original dataframe to create new dataframes, since I know if you let b = a, then whatever you did to a will also be reflected in b. But it still does not work.

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv(...)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values, index=df1.index, columns=['a'])
df3 = pd.DataFramd(df1.values, index=df1.index, columns=['a'])

results = [5,6,111,112,145,148] # an example for demonstration
ss_index = list(df1.index[5:6]) + list(df1.index[111:112]) + 
           list(df1.index[145:148])
nss_index = df1.index.difference(ss_index)

df2.loc[ss_index, :] = np.nan # this set all three dfs at ss_index to nan
df3.loc[nss_index, :] = np.nan # this sets all three dfs at nss_index to nan
```

New edit: .copy is a super useful attribute. numpy, pandas and a lot of libraries have .copy built in. If not, one could import copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first assignment sets `ss_index` values to `np.nan` which are only indices `[5,111,145,146,147]`. The second one sets `nss_index` indices to `np.nan` which are the indices different from `ss_index`, basically all the remaining indices. Since `df2` and `df3` are just a reference to `df1`, when you modify one of them, all of them are modified.

You can create a copy of the values in the Dataframe using `.copy()` method,

```
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
```

Now, `df2` won't be affected by the changes in `df1`

Comment: Thanks! So even I used df1.values to convert df1 to arrays when I was creating df2 and df3, they are still references to df1. How does this work?